# Excel VBA to Save As with "." (period) in File Name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in excel 2013 that autofills the file name in the Save As dialog box with the value of cell C20. However when the name contains a period such as "ABC_12.1_2017" the file name field in the Save As dialog box is blank. If I remove the period(s) the correct name appears.

It seems that this exact problem was solved in [this forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/999024-save-file-as-pdf-with-period-in-file-name.html), but I read through the solution and can't understand what was changed. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
Sub SaveAsNew()
'opens save as with the filename prefilled by value of c20 and hides the copy template sheet
        ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Sheets("Copy Template").Range("c20")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Range("d1").value` where d1 =testing.this.out and `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show "testing.this.out"` also works for me.  What is Activesheet value and c20's value in yours.

Comment: The solution in that link was to use `GetSaveAsFileName` instead of the dialog `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs)`

Comment: C20's value would be something like "ABC_12.1_2017". I erased all of my code and used your `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Range("d1").value` where d1 =testing.this.out, and the box was still empty. Does my version of excel not support the same functions as yours?

Comment: Do you need to have access to the "Save As" window or all you need is for the document to be saved as the value in cell C20 no matter what?
Should it overwrite your file or create a new one?

Comment: I think I need the "Save As" window because the location where the file needs to be saved will always be different. However, I think I can work with the solution you suggested with a little extra work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome :)
I believe there is something to do to ease the workload by going with a Cell Value or a Variable that you can change on the spot before saving, perhaps even use text reference to get to the different paths without manually editing anything (depends where and how your folder directories are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

---

There is a Windows/Excel specific issues where it is impossible to fetch a value containing a period and pasting it in an Active Window. It works on some computer and doesn't on others.

Even attempting to add a period anywhere in the save name with VBA by using Chr or a text string doesn't work.

In the below scenario, Range("C20") was the value "Cat" and it still appeared blank in both cases as I attempted to add a period.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (Sheets("Template").Range("c20") & Chr(46) & "xlsm")
```

or

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (Sheets("Template").Range("c20") & "." & "xlsm")
```

---

**Solution:**

---

While I do not know the root cause of that issue, there is a way to bypass this by using the SaveAs command instead.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\YOUR DIRECTORY\" & Worksheets("Copy Template").Range("C20") & ".xlsm"
```

This will save the workbook without opening a Save As window using the value in .Range("c20"). I experience the same issue as you with the previous methods and I can confirm that this works.

If you prefer, you can even read the path from a Variable or a Cell value instead of the "C:\YOUR DIRECTORY\" text string.

That would give you this script:

```
Sub SaveAsNew()
'Saves As with the filename prefilled by value of C20 at the specified directory and hides the copy template sheet.
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\YOUR DIRECTORY\" & Worksheets("Copy Template").Range("C20") & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```